# Mongoose - Access object property with spaces

Tags: node.js, mongoose, stripe-payments

I'm handling data imported to a MongoDb Collection from a Stripe-generated CSV of customers. Some fields from this CSV have spaces in the name, like Card ID, Card Brand and many others.

I'm having a problem accessing these name in the resulting objects of a *.find()* query:

```
StripeCustomer.find().then(
(customers) => {
  console.log("customer[1]:", customers[1]);
  console.log("id:", customers[1]['id']);
  console.log("Card ID:", customers[1]['Card ID']);
  res.json({
    code: 200,
    message: 'success',
    total: customers.length,
    data: customers
  })
}
```

The Card ID property returns *undefined*.

I tried using *encodeURIComponent* or other string conversion functions for the property name *customers[0][encodeURIComponent('Card ID')]* but without result.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it using the *.get()* function:

```
console.log("Card ID:", customers[1].get('Card ID'));
```

I hope this can save somebody else's time.

Cheers!